# Pinescript/TradingView How to make compost expression

Tags: pine-script, trading

I can't build a expression with 2 conditions

In the first example I tried to use 'and' without success.

```
dayofmonth == 1 and month == 1
```

[image]

---

Only the month works as expected
[image]

---

Only the dayofmonth works as expected
[image]

---

Again tried to use both together, this time with nested 'if', but only the outside is executed.
[image]

Are someone experienced with this?

Answer (score 0):

The conditions work. Do you want an `or` instead of `and`? `dayofmonth == 1 and month == 1` will only be true Jan. 1st.

```
//@version=4
study("conditions test", overlay=true)
a = dayofmonth == 1
b = month == 1
c = a and b

plotshape(a, style=shape.circle, color=color.purple, size=size.small)
plotshape(b, style=shape.circle, color=color.red, size=size.small)
plotshape(c, style=shape.circle, color=color.green, size=size.small)
```

[image: Day and Month Test]